# Erro endpoit minimal API MapGet .net core 6 usando Guid

Tags: c#, api, oracle, asp.net-core

Estava seguindo um tutorial para implementar uma minimal API em .net core 6. No entanto, no tutorial foi utilizado SQL Server e eu estou implementando com Oracle.

Os verbos POST e GET funcionaram corretamente, ou seja, conexão com banco está ok, inserindo dados e obtendo a lista de todos os registros.

Quando tentei implementar o verbo GET passando o parâmetro Id (que no caso é um Guid), apresentou erro na requisição da API pelo Swagger.

Alguém já passou por esse problema ou saberia me explicar por quê do erro abaixo?

**Classe Fornecedor.cs:**

```html
namespace EstudyMinimalAPI_01.Models
{
    public class Fornecedor
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string? Nome { get; set; }
        public string? Documento { get; set; }
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Classe MinimalContextDb.cs:**

```html
using EstudyMinimalAPI_01.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EstudyMinimalAPI_01.Data
{
    public class MinimalContextDb : DbContext
    {
        public MinimalContextDb(DbContextOptions<MinimalContextDb> options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Fornecedor>().HasKey(f => f.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Fornecedor>().Property(f => f.Nome).IsRequired().HasColumnType("varchar2(200)");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Fornecedor>().Property(f => f.Documento).IsRequired().HasColumnType("varchar2(14)");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Fornecedor>().ToTable("Fornecedores");

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

**Arquivo Program.cs:**

```html
using EstudyMinimalAPI_01.Data;
using EstudyMinimalAPI_01.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

#region Configuration

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MinimalContextDb>(options =>
    options.UseOracle(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

#endregion Configuration

#region Fornecedor

#region GetFornecedor

app.MapGet("/fornecedor", async (
    MinimalContextDb context) =>
    await context.Fornecedores.ToListAsync())
    .WithName("GetFornecedor")
    .WithTags("Fornecedor");

#endregion GetFornecedor

#region GetFornecedorById

app.MapGet("/fornecedor/{id}", async (
    Guid id,
    MinimalContextDb context) =>
    await context.Fornecedores.FindAsync(id)
        is Fornecedor fornecedor 
        ? Results.Ok(fornecedor) 
        : Results.NotFound())
    .Produces<Fornecedor>(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
    .Produces<Fornecedor>(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
    .WithName("GetFornecedorById")
    .WithTags("Fornecedor");

#endregion GetFornecedorById

#region PostFornecedor

app.MapPost("/fornecedor", async (
    MinimalContextDb context,
    Fornecedor fornecedor) =>
{
    context.Fornecedores.Add(fornecedor);
    var result = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
})
    .Produces<Fornecedor>(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
    .Produces<Fornecedor>(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)
    .WithName("PostFornecedor")
    .WithTags("Fornecedor");

#endregion PostFornecedor

#endregion Fornecedor

app.Run();
```

**EndPoint com Erro:**

```html
app.MapGet("/fornecedor/{id}", async (
    Guid id,
    MinimalContextDb context) =>
    await context.Fornecedores.FindAsync(id)
        is Fornecedor fornecedor 
        ? Results.Ok(fornecedor) 
        : Results.NotFound())
    .Produces<Fornecedor>(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
    .Produces<Fornecedor>(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
    .WithName("GetFornecedorById")
    .WithTags("Fornecedor");
```

**Imagens do Erro:**

[image: Requisição Swagger Imagem 1]

[image: Requisição Swagger Imagem 2]

[image: Requisição Swagger Imagem 3]

[image: Requisição Swagger Imagem 4]

**Mensagem de Erro:**

```html
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00933: comando SQL não encerrado adequadamente at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone) at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, Int64 internalInitialJSONFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF) at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior) at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Program.<>c.<<
$>b__0_2>d.MoveNext() in C:\Cursos\Youtube\Desenvolvedor.io\EstudyMinimalAPI_01\EstudyMinimalAPI_01\Program.cs:line 44 --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.ExecuteTaskResult[T](Task`1 task, HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) HEADERS ======= Accept: application/json Host: localhost:7255 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 :method: GET Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7 Cookie: Phpstorm-300075c6=7db351ba-7aa0-45a1-bd03-a22a1cddfc3e,Webstorm-25d0da6a=a218a17e-7d35-4331-975e-f576e695fc03 Referer: https://localhost:7255/swagger/index.html sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24" sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0 sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows" sec-fetch-site: same-origin sec-fetch-mode: cors sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Comment: *"o verbo GET passando o parâmetro Id (que no caso é um Guid)"* não está faltando definir corretamente que o parâmetro é um Guid ou algo assim? Tente usar outro método tbm como o `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, validando a expressão, algo como  `FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == id)`;

Comment: @RicardoPontual, obrigado pela sugestão! Na passagem dos parametros está tipado como "Guid". Tentei implementar da maneira que sugeriu, mas continua com mesmo erro. Tentei também alterar o tipo para "string", mas não aceitou, deu conflito porque a classe está com "Guid".

Comment: pode pudar na api para string se quiser tentar, e usar por exemplo `new Guid(id)`, o objetivo seria apenas identificar se o problema é o id/conversão, pq o resto entity framework faz sozinho

Comment: Alterei para string no projeto todo e testei... Métodos Get e Post continuam normal com string mesmo... Mas o GetPorId deu o mesmo erro... Deve ser algo com EF e ORACLE.